# Ubuntu 20.04 permissions inherited from group

Tags: 20.04, permissions, transmission

I've really tried to find the solution everywhere, but still don't get it.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I want transmission, plex, sonarr and radarr to access folders to be able to download files. For this I've decided to add all these users to a group called 'htpc'.

```
htpc@htpc:~$ getent group htpc
htpc:x:1000:root,www-data,sonarr,radarr,plex,debian-transmission
```

I have /media/hdd2/Filmek folder owned by htpc:htpc (user/group).

```
htpc@htpc:~$ ls -la /media/hdd2/
total 88
drwxrwsrwx+  14 htpc                htpc                 4096 Aug 24 14:57  .
drwxr-xr-x    7 debian-transmission debian-transmission  4096 Aug  1 11:01  ..
drwxrwsrwx+   3 htpc                htpc                 4096 Aug  1 09:41  Downloads
drwxrwsr-x+ 112 htpc                htpc                20480 Jul 25 13:25  Filmek
drwxrwsrwx+   3 htpc                htpc                 4096 Sep 29  2019  Kids
drwxrwsrwx+   2 htpc                htpc                16384 Jun  2  2019  lost+found
-rwxrwxrwx+   1 htpc                htpc                 1632 Nov  7  2019  lovelace.yaml
drwxrwsrwx   11 htpc                htpc                 4096 Sep  7 17:34  Osmo
drwxr-sr-x    3 www-data            htpc                 4096 Aug 24 16:10  owncloud
drwxrwsrwx+   2 htpc                htpc                 4096 Mar 19 18:14  Photos
drwxrwsrwx+   4 htpc                htpc                 4096 Feb 28  2020  Requested
drwxrwsrwx+   3 htpc                htpc                 4096 Nov  4  2019  Stuffs
drwxrwsrwx+  51 htpc                htpc                 4096 Sep  7 17:59 'Szinkronos sorozatok'
drwxrwsrwx+   4 htpc                htpc                 4096 Aug  4  2019  .Trash-1000
drwxrwsrwx+   3 htpc                htpc                 4096 Jun  5  2020  Zene
```

Doesn't it mean, user 'radarr' should have access to write this folder without any problem?

Still if Radarr tries to import a file, I get this error message:

> [v3.2.2.5080] System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
> Access to the path '/media/hdd2/Filmek/Friends The Reunion (2021)/Friends.the.Reunion.2021...mkv' is denied.

**EDIT**

The output of `getfacl /media/hdd2/Filmek` is:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names   
# file: media/hdd2/Filmek   
# owner: htpc # group: htpc   
# flags: -s- user::rwx group::rwx group:plex:rwx mask::rwx other::r-x
```

And the output of `getfacl /media/hdd2/Filmek/Friends\ The\ Reunion\ (2021)/` is:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names 
# file: media/hdd2/Filmek/Friends The Reunion (2021)/ 
# owner: htpc 
# group: htpc 
# flags: -s- user::rwx group::rwx other::r-x
```

And the output of `getfacl /media/torrent/Downloads/incomplete/Radarr/Friends.the.Reunion.2021.1080p.HMAX.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264.HUN.ENG-PTHD/Friends.the.Reunion.2021.1080p.HMAX.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264.HUN.ENG-PTHD.mkv` is:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names  
# file: media/torrent/Downloads/incomplete/Radarr/Friends.the.Reunion.2021.1080p.HMAX.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264.HUN.ENG-PTHD/Friends.the.Reunion.2021.1080p.HMAX.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264.HUN.ENG-PTHD.mkv 
# owner: debian-transmission 
# group: htpc user::rw- group::r-- other::r--
```

Comment: You need to assure your user has permissions to read/write in the destination folders. All the apps are running with your user.

Comment: Radarr is running by user: radarr, transmission is running by user transmission-daemon. Both user are members of group htpc. Isn't this how it supposed to work?

Comment: No, it isn't. Again, check the destination folders permissions.

Comment: Okay, so help me out. How should permissions work? I have a library which should be written by application Plex (ran by user plex), application Radarr, (ran by user radarr) application Sonarr (ran by user sonarr). If I chown for plex:plex, then sonarr, radarr won't have permission...

Comment: 1) There is a `+` after the permissions field on both `.` and `Filmek` which means additional access control lists are in affect on these directories. Check if they are not getting in your way by `getfacl <path>`.
2) What are the permissions on folder `/media/hdd2/Filmek/Friends The Reunion (2021)/`, because you wanted to load a file from that folder. And what are the permissions on the file itself?

Comment: @syluccy: I merged your two comments with the question. Next time, please do it yourself and do not add additional information as comments, but rather as edits to your question. Thanks.